# Selecting a radom file from a directory

Tags: c#

I want to build my random folder movie player.

If I understand correctly, all I need to do is add another public method at the very top that specifies which directory to play files randomly, correct?

```
WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer Player;

private void PlayFile(String url)
{
    Player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
    Player.PlayStateChange += 
        new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(Player_PlayStateChange);
    Player.MediaError += 
        new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_MediaErrorEventHandler(Player_MediaError);
    Player.URL = url;
    Player.controls.play();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO  Insert a valid path in the line below.
    PlayFile(@"c:\myaudio.wma");
}

private void Player_PlayStateChange(int NewState)
{
    if ((WMPLib.WMPPlayState)NewState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
}

private void Player_MediaError(object pMediaObject)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Cannot play media file.");
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: I'm not clear why your asking us this? It's your code?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to randomly play media files in a specific directory, right?
There are many ways to do this. For example, you can get all files with specific extensions in a specific folder, store them in array, and then you can use **Linq** to order the array by a random number like the following

```
public bool IsMediaFile(string fileNameWithExtension)
{
    return fileNameWithExtension.EndsWith(".mp3")
           || fileNameWithExtension.EndsWith(".wmv")
           || fileNameWithExtension.EndsWith(".avi");
}
public Task<IEnumerable<string>> GetMediaFilesInDirectory(string path)
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew<IEnumerable<string>>(() =>
    {
        var random = new Random();
        var originalPathsArray = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
            .Where(IsMediaFile).ToArray();
        return originalPathsArray.OrderBy(e => random.Next()).ToArray();
    });
}
```

This first method will check if the file is a media file by checking its extension, of course there are better ways to do that sort of thing.
The second method accept one parameter of type string, which is the directory path that you want to look for the media files inside of it.
 It returns `Task<IEnumerable<string>>`

1. `Task<T>`
   because I asked the `GetFiles` method to search recursively inside all of the child directories and that will take long time -well it depends-. You can change this behavior of course!
2. `IEnumerable<string>`
   because I want to return multiple strings, it's like an array of strings but in a generic way!

**Note**
I highly suggest that you separate the media player logic from the form logic by passing in an interface type of a custom media player service, this way there will be no explicit dependency between the form and the actual implementation of your media player.

---

Hope this has helped you in a way or another!

Answer (score 0):

You could instantiate your `Form1` passing to its constructor the path to the directory that contains the media files that can be played:

```
public class Form1 : Form
{
    WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer Player;
    String m_Directory;

    public Form1(String directory)
    {
        m_Directory = directory;
    }

    private void PlayFile(String url)
    {
        Player = new WMPLib.WindowsMediaPlayer();
        Player.PlayStateChange += 
            new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEventHandler(Player_PlayStateChange);
        Player.MediaError += 
            new WMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_MediaErrorEventHandler(Player_MediaError);
        Player.URL = url;
        Player.controls.play();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        var di = new DirectoryInfo(m_Directory);
        var files = di.GetFiles("*.*").Where(f => f.Extension.ToLowerInvariant() == ".wma");

        Random random = new Random();
        Int32 randomIndex = random.Next(0,files.Count());
        var file = files.ElementAt(randomIndex).FullName;

        PlayFile(file);
    }

    private void Player_PlayStateChange(int NewState)
    {
        if ((WMPLib.WMPPlayState)NewState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsStopped)
            this.Close();
    }

    private void Player_MediaError(object pMediaObject)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cannot play media file.");
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could implement a `FolderBrowserDialog` in `Form1` and let the user pick the directory that contains the media files that can be played (preferably not in the `Form1_Load` event):

```
private void PlayRandomButton_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();

    if (result != DialogResult.OK)
        return;

    String directory = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;

    var di = new DirectoryInfo(directory);
    var files = di.GetFiles("*.*").Where(f => f.Extension.ToLowerInvariant() == ".wma");

    Random random = new Random();
    Int32 randomIndex = random.Next(0,files.Count());
    var file = files.ElementAt(randomIndex).FullName;

    PlayFile(file);
}
```

In my code the filter on `.wma` files could be modified or improved in order to allow different types of file to be played. For example:

```
private static String[] s_Extensions = new String[] { ".mp3", ".wma", ".wmv" };

// ...

var files = di.GetFiles("*.*").Where( f => s_Extensions.Contains( f.Extension.ToLowerInvariant()));
```